# datepicker has no images for next and prev

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am using the datepicker using these libraries

#### js

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

#### css

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

and i got this result

[image]

see there are no images on `next` and `prev`

any help?

Comment: Check your CSS paths to the images, and the console to see where the browser is looking.

Comment: @j08691 i use `F12` in google chrome and it doesn't tell me that there is errors. Also, where should i look in my css? it is huge :)

Comment: Are you actually linking to the `code.jquery.com` hosted `jquery-ui.css`, or are you hosting it on your server?

Comment: @CWSpear i am hosting them in my server

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `jquery-ui.css` file, you can find some references to images (I started out by searching for `url(`). Those references are pointing to files in `images/`, which means it is looking for files in an `images` folder relative to that CSS file.

You mentioned you're hosting the CSS on your server. So for example, let's say this is your directory structure:

```
/
|__jquery-ui/
   |__smoothness/
      |__jquery-ui.css
```

You would need to create an images folder in the `smoothness` directory and place the images that should have come with your jQueryUI download in there (if you don't have them, go to jQuery UI's site and redownload them).

Your file structure should look something like this (the important thing to note is the `images/` directory in the same directory as `jquery-ui.css`):

```
/
|__jquery-ui/
   |__smoothness/
      |__jquery-ui.css
      |__images/
         |__ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
         |__ui-icons_888888_256x240.png
         |__etc...
```

**Alternatively**, you can just link directly to the CSS file on a CDN, such as `code.jquery.com` and it will have all the images in the correct place. You can just replace your link to jQuery UI's CSS with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```